# excel formula: search a range of cells and return the value of the only non-blank cell

Tags: excel-formula

This should be an easy formula but for some reason, i can't figure it out.

I have many rows with formulas and each row spreads over many columns (e.g. A-Z).  However, in each row, there is only one value in one of the columns and all other columns are blank.

I need a formula that will search each row of data (e.g. A1:Z1) and return me the value of the only 'non-blank' cell.

why can't i figure this out?  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=HLOOKUP("*", A1:Z1,1,0)
```

Comment: thanks for trying to answer this.  the formula almost works.  the function argument 'row_index_num', or '1', in the formula you proposed only returns a value if there is something in the first column (column 'A').  the data could be in any column from column 'A' through column 'Z'.  therefore, it seems like the '1' in your formula is 'static', and i need something 'dynamic'.  makes sense?  hope i'm communicating clearly.  thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The formula works just fine for me.  The 1 indicates to get it from the first row of the range, not the first column.  So it is looking in range A1:Z1 for any value, and when it finds a value it returns a result from the corresponding column in row 1.  Since there is only 1 row, the formula simply returns the value it found

Comment: @user2752146 Formula works for range A1:Z1. You may be running into a value or format issue. This formula works on text, not numbers.

Comment: yeah, you are correct...i just figured out what is happening...there are formulas in every column.  All formulas have IF statements and only one of the formulas is true in each row and the true formula returns a value.  the hlookup formula mentioned above isn't differentiating between whether the first column has a true statement (and therefore shows a value) or if it is false and returns a blank value ("").  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

If your blank cells are "" just do

> =SUM(A1:Z1)